# Google Drive system tray icon gone

Tags: google-drive

I have (had) Google Drive installed on a Windows 7 laptop.

Normally Drive starts during logon, and the system tray icon appears.

However, now the system tray icon never appears.

Google Drive is set to load at startup in msconfig (C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe).

2 instances of googledrivesync.exe are showing in Task Manager.  1 is using 56,000 K, the other 760 K.

I'd like to know if my local Google Drive is up to date, and the system tray icon is the usual way I can tell.

Comment: Does Drive work (sync) when you place files in its folder? If it does then there's nothing wrong with the actual program. And have you checked that the tray icon has not been accidentally hidden? This is a common mistake.

Comment: @Jonah: How do I check if the tray icon has been hidden?

Comment: Rightclick the tray area and click customize

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google Product Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/9ExvojxXldI) this can occur if the folder on your local machine that is used to synchronise to Google Drive is marked as hidden.

Try unsetting the hidden attribute of:
*C:\Users\~username~\AppData\Local\Google* 
and all its subfolders and files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chenmunka.  Google and its subfolders are not hidden.